# Does timeEndPeriod restore the previous or the default value?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Say the default timer resolution is 15ms. Given this scenario:

```
Process A calls timeBeginPeriod(1);
Now timer resolution is 1ms.
Process B calls timeBeginPeriod(2);
Now timer resolution is 2ms.
Process B calls timeEndPeriod(2);
```

What is the timer resolution then? Does it fall back to 1 or 15ms?

Let's modify the scenario a bit:

```
Process A calls timeBeginPeriod(1);
Now timer resolution is 1ms.
Process B calls timeBeginPeriod(2);
Now timer resolution is 2ms.
Process A calls timeEndPeriod(1);
```

Now what is the timer resolution? Does it stay at 2ms until process B calls timeEndPeriod(2)?

Comment: What's "unclear" about the question? timeEndPeriod is a function of the Win32 API as indicated by the question tags (i.e. winapi). The timer is the timer set by this function, obviously. If you don't know about it, then just don't answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Windows uses the lowest value (that is, highest resolution) requested by any process.

Assuming that your processes are the only ones to call `timeBeginPeriod()` then:

> Q: What is the timer resolution then? Does it fall back to 1 or 15ms?

It didn't change because 1 ms (what required by process A) was the lowest resolution (then the applied one). So answer is: it was 1 ms and it didn't change when process B made its request, because it's a global setting then most restrictive (lowest) one is applied.

> Q: Now what is the timer resolution? Does it stay at 2ms until process B calls timeEndPeriod(2)?

Yes, because now lowest required resolution is 2 ms so system will honor that request until `timeEndPeriod(2)` is called.